# Material design lite not formating form elements on navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design-lite, angularjs-1.5

I'm using material design lite for a proof of concept. I have a page with a form that will be pre-populated with backend data when loading. I noticed that when navigating using angular, the form field label format is not applied correctly

[image]

when accessing the url directly, reloading the page or modifying the value in the input, the format is applied as expected

[image]

Code

```
<div class="mdl-cell--12-col">
    <div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="vm.benefit.name">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Nombre</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="2" id="description" ng-model="vm.benefit.description"></textarea>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="description">Descripción</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell--4-col">
        <h6>Tipo</h6>
        <ul class="demo-list-control mdl-list">
            <li class="mdl-list__item" ng-repeat="type in vm.benefitTypes">
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                    {{type.text}}
                </span>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action">
                    <label class="demo-list-radio mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="list-option-{{type.id}}">
                        <input type="radio" id="list-option-{{type.id}}" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="Descuento directo"  ng-model="vm.benefit.type" checked />
                    </label>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Calling `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()` does not make any change. Any clue?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your form to bring more help?

Comment: @JonathanBrizio I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

When you populate the content on the input you're missing to add the class `is-dirty` to each input field initially. You can check the behavior of that component here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjRLVL

Keep rocking!